# Node.js -Firebase Service Account Private Key won't parse

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, npm, firebase-authentication

I use `.env` variables in my app.js file to access the keys. Everything was working fine until I downloaded a new `Firebase Service Account Private Key`. When I replaced the old value with the new value I can no longer access the key because in `terminal` when I run `node app.js` I keep getting an error message:

> /Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:129
>               throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL,
>   'Failed to parse private key: ' + error);
>               ^
>
> Error: Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted
>   message.
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
>       at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:119:28)
>       at new Certificate (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:129:19)
>       at new CertCredential (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:192:64)
>       at Object.cert (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/.....)
>       at Object. (/Users/Cpu/Desktop/...../app.js:14:32)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)   at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor]
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1

All I did was c+p the new `Private Key` and then added it and saved the `.env` file, pushed to heroku, and it's no longer working. I even downloaded a new `Private Key` but the same problem occurs.

The old and new Private Keys

```
// old Private Key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nbbbbbbbb\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n

// new Private Key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nzzzzzzzz\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

The .env file:

```
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=wwwwwwww
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=xxxxxxxx
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=yyyyyyyy
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nzzzzzzzz\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

The app.js file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,   // I get no error here
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,   // I get no error here
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY   // I get error HERE
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
```

**How can I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The problem was since I used `dotenv` variables inside the `.env` file the `FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY` had escaping characters: `\n` inside of it.

I had to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41044630/4833705) and append `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')` to the end of it to parse it:

```
privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

So now the code looks like:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID, // I get no error here
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL, // I get no error here
      privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n') // NOW THIS WORKS!!!
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
```

Comment: I'm having this problem after creating new keys in Firebase. I'm keeping the key values in Firebase Environmental Variables, so I shouldn't have to adjust for `\n`. When I `firebase deploy --only functions`, I get the PEM error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I never user Firebase  env vars before. I wish I could help

Comment: This solved my issue. Strange thing was it worked without it, then suddenly stopped working. Anyway, voted this up for others to see.

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen the same exact thing happened to me. It was working without it then for some strange after I changed to a new private key and tried again it no longer worked. Very odd. Anyway glad I could help and thanks for the upvote. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly with firebase config variables. e.g accessing    functions.config().var.name.replace(/\\n/g, '\n') (set via    firebase functions:config:set var.name="xxx"
).

Comment: I had to add: .replace(/\\\\n/g, '\n') in order to replace the //n correctly

Comment: I had same situation on AWS elastic beanstalk, I added `\\n` instead of `\n` in the environment variables and added replace where I access them.

Comment: after many days and nights I finally have success. I send you my deepest gratitudes

Comment: had same problem, used the raplce but also had to add \n to the very start of the key

Comment: @AbishekKumar where did you add the `\\n` do you mean in the private_key="asd\n" or in the replace() ?

Comment: You are correct! It worked for me!

Answer (score 39):

You must add your key into double qoutes to allow expanded new lines option according with `dotenv` documentation.

You can check that option at Rules section in `dotenv` github.

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#rules

```
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=wwwwwwww
  FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=xxxxxxxx
  FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=yyyyyyyy
  FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nzzzzzzzz\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Update : 2022

If anyone still looking for solution with below configurations, here's how I solved it.

Stack:

TypeScript
Express
Dotenv
Heroku

**CONVERT THE ENTIRE JSON FILE TO BASE64**

Use this link to convert [Base64 Encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/) or you can use any other tools as well.

Add the Encoded String in your .env

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=<your_large_base64_string>
```

Then below is the code for `firebase-init.ts` to consume the keys.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

declare var process: {
    env: {
        FIREBASE_KEYS: string;
    }
}
const initializeFirebaseAdmin = (isProd = true) => {
    const firebase_private_key_b64 = Buffer.from(process.env.FIREBASE_KEYS, 'base64');
    const firebase_private_key = firebase_private_key_b64.toString('utf8');
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(JSON.parse(firebase_private_key))
    });
}


export { initializeFirebaseAdmin }
```

Comment: To keep your app secure, don't share your private key with untrusted third parties.  There's also no need to convert to /from base 64, as previous answers show.

Answer (score 0):

I believe cert function is wating JSON object
try converting the key into JSON and i think it will work

```
credential: admin.credential.cert(JSON.parse(serviceAccountKey))
```

this worked for me !

Comment: it shows 
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @PiyushPandey I had the same issue. I'm using dotenv and I was requiring dotenv after the file i was using it in, so that fixed it for me. Might be unhelpful, but just letting you know that's what did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me I just put the whole service acount in my `.env` file like so:

**.env**

```
FIREBASE_ADMIN_API={"type":..."private_key":"..."...}
```

Then I import it like so:

**server.ts**

```js
const firebase_admin_config = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_API);

getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp({
  credential: credential.cert(firebase_admin_config)
}) : getApp();
```

Answer (score -3):

Generate admin SDK Firebase under <kbd>Firebase</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Admin SDK Firebase</kbd>. Go to Google Cloud Platform in your project, click in <kbd>IAM administrator</kbd> > <kbd>Source account</kbd>, and generate the key code in account service (your account service is generated in the admin SDK Firebase).