# Errors when trying to authenticate Firebase SDK admin to getDownloadURL

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase and I want to use Cloud Functions to get access to `getDownloadURL` of my images so that I can use it in an image tag.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064882/how-to-get-getdownloadurl-from-onfinalize-cloud-function) which helped me get some structure but I got the following error:

> Error: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.

I learnt that this is caused by authentication and service account related issues.

So installed the admin-SDK and then I tried following these instructions on the Firebase console page:
[image]

And here is my code but cloud functions is telling me that there is something wrong with my code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firestore = admin.firestore();

const serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

exports.imageFirestoreCreate = functions.storage.bucket().object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const newFile = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket).file(object.name);
    const config = { action: 'read', expires: '01-01-2033' };
    const downloadUrls = await newFile.getSignedUrl(config);
    const downloadUrl = downloadUrls[0];
        
    const images = firestore.collection("images");
    await images.add({
      imageURL: downloadUrl,
    });
});
```

In case you need to know this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^7.0.1",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "sib-api-v3-sdk": "^8.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I get the following error  and i've been struggling to figure it out:

   > Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
2. I know that service account keys are unsafe but i need to ask. I created a json service account and its referenced in this document, I'm expected to keep it safe. But where do you keep it since its going to be used by your functions which are in your project which will be uploaded to cloud hosting. Do you keep it in your project and gitignore them?

Comment: For #2, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612154/firebase-creditentials-json-file-in-github.

Comment: Normally you don't need to use a service account when you initialize an admin app instance, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=1st#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app_1) in the doc. Have you tried that?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, i did but it still gave me the ```client_email``` error. Do you think firebase emulator has anything to do with it?

Comment: Did you try to deploy and test it?

Comment: I have not. If one more thing "only works in a live environment and not in the emulator", that might be the straw that breaks the camels back for me. Not sure what the point of an emulator is anymore.

Comment: Yes, but it is interesting, in the frame of a debugging/solution finding approach to see if it is the same when deployed.